# What (in layman's terms) is Authentication Middleware?

Tags: node.js, passport.js

Getting started with server-side and especially Node.js. Stumbled upon this authentications framework called Passport.js, built specifically for Node. Would someone take the liberty to explain this Authentication Middleware thing to me? In layman's terms, if possible. Thanks ;)

Comment: Joe Clay yeah sorry about that, I just changed it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Authentication Middleware is any number of authentication-related functions that are executed prior to passing the request to its final route. For example, any routes requiring the user to be logged in would run Authentication Middleware before serving the resource.

Comment: So its like a security check to ensure the user is logged in?

Comment: In that particular example, yes. It could be used to authenticate other things like user privileges etc.

Comment: And Its used in situations where privacy matters so if there is a server where the user has stored private information, it runs a check to then gain access to the user?